# How to use Async/Await with a task of integer

Tags: vb.net, async-await

Seen questions similar to this, clearly async/await is confusing especially for those of us that have been coding synchronously for years. Trying to understand how to use it with a function that counts how many executions were successful.

So assuming I have an rest api that calls ExecuteSendMultipleMessages() and returns the count of messages sent. How would I convert so that this can run async? As you can see the final worker that does the work (SendMessageAsync) supports async, so at the moment I return .Result directly.

Tried converting it myself but I can't understand how to return a Task(of Integer) in SendMultipleMessages that checks if the message was sent okay. This is all pseudocode, but my real code is very similar.

```
Function ExecuteSendMultipleMessages() as Integer
    Dim RecipientsFromDb = GetThemFromSomewhere()
    Dim CountSent = SendMultipleMessages(RecipientsFromDb)
    Return CountSent
End Function


Function SendMultipleMessages(ListOfRecipients) as Integer
    Dim SuccessCount as integer
    
    For each EmailItem in ListOfRecipients
        Dim SentOk = SendEmail(SomeMsgObjectUsingEmailItem)
        if SentOk
            SuccessCount += 1
        end if
    next
    return SuccessCount
End Function


Function SendEmail(Msg as Message) as Boolean
    'do work here, returns true or false
    
    try
        return SomeObject.SendMessageAsync(Msg).Result
                
    catch as Exception
        return false
    end try
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Async / Await. Note, the emails are sent sequentially

```vb
Public Async Function ExecuteSendMultipleMessagesAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
    Dim RecipientsFromDb = GetThemFromSomewhere()
    Dim CountSent = Await SendMultipleMessagesAsync(RecipientsFromDb)
    Return CountSent
End Function

Public Function SendMultipleMessagesAsync(ListOfRecipients) As Task(Of Integer)
    Return Task.Run(
        Async Function()
            Dim SuccessCount As Integer
            For Each EmailItem In ListOfRecipients
                Dim SentOk = Await SendEmailAsync(SomeMsgObjectUsingEmailItem)
                If SentOk Then SuccessCount += 1
            Next
            Return SuccessCount
        End Function)
End Function

Public Async Function SendEmailAsync(Msg As Message) As Task(Of Boolean)
    'do work here, returns true or false
    Try
        Return Await SomeObject.SendMessageAsync(Msg)
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

To call

```vb
Public Async Sub Foo()
    Await instance.ExecuteSendMultipleMessagesAsync()
End Sub
```

I believe the messages could be set in parallel with the following

```vb
Public Function SendMultipleMessagesAsync(ListOfRecipients) As Task(Of Integer)
    Return Task.Run(
        Async Function()
            Return (Await Task.WhenAll(ListOfRecipients.Select(Function(r) SendEmailAsync(r)))).Count(Function(b) b)
        End Function)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I'm understaing the first bit, it means if I want to check the return status for each execution, then it can only happen sequentially. So if I want them to run at the same time, I might have to use an event or find some other way to log the status of each execution.  Let me try your solution and post back if I get stuck. Many thanks.

Comment: The `Await` only means you won't block the calling thread while it waits for the result. To achieve parallelism you can use `Task.WhenAll` on multiple `Tasks` like in the second version of the method. `Await` on an individual `Task` vs. on multiple `Task` is the distinction.

Comment: Indeed. Your last function is what I used, worked like a charm. Sending multiple messages now takes half the time it used to before. Thanks for your answer @djv